# How to remove links generated by SEO-smart-links?

Tags: plugins, links, uninstallation

I tried seo-smart-links plugin and it linked all my posts to tags/categories and other posts. This looks stuffing and spamming to me so I uninstalled this plugin. Now the links are still there but the plugin author said links are created on the fly so they will be removed after uninstallation but it didn't.

Kindly let me know how can I revert it and remove those links created by this plugin. You can have a look at [technostall.com](http://www.technostall.com) to see the situation.

Comment: Do you use a caching plugin? If so: have you emptied the cache completely? And have you checked the actual post content?

Comment: I'm not using any cache plugin, I also noticed that the option "Delete" is not working in "Plugins". Although I've deactived this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Although I was not using any cache plugin but the plugin itself had a setting of saving cache on visitor's site. I tried on other browsers and it's not there. So the problem is resolved.